# Optimize API call

Tags: node.js, optimization, mern

I am working on a designing app like canva. User can create a design and system will automatically keep saving every change user made. On backend it is generating of preview of that design and uploading it to s3 bucket. But this processing will greatly increase load on the backend. how can this be optimized to save processing?

Comment: Simplest answer is to generate fewer previews. You can cache the "time of last preview" for a particular design, then only generate the new preview when time of last preview is >= a certain threshold (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc).

Alternatively, analyze why you need previews, and see if you can adjust for that. If you only need previews because of the user's home page or something, then you could only generate previews when the user leaves the editing page, for example. 

Third option would be to decrease the resolution of your previews, making it less computationally expensive to upload.

Comment: @NateNorris couple of your points are thoughtful. like generating previews in the home page list but it will add delay there!!!